# Simplifying the expression: $5(a+b)+2(a+c)-4(b+c)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$5(a+b)+2(a+c)-4(b+c)=7a+b-2c$$

I know the equation is solved correctly but I would just like some explanation of why and how it was solved. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just by [expanding](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/expanding.html), we obtain:
$$\color{red}{5(a+b)}+\color{green}{2(a+c)}-\color{blue}{4(b+c)}=\color{red}{(5a+5b)}+\color{green}{(2a+2c)}-\color{blue}{(4b+4c)}$$
Taking care of the brackets then simplifying everything, we obtain the desired result:
$$5a+5b+2a+2c-4b-4c=7a+b-2c$$

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I needed